# Ansible reboot server if task warns

Tags: ansible, yaml

I task a task that disables selinux on a managed host before performing an installation.

However ansible returning a warning informing that reboot is needed for setting to take effect:

```
TASK [Gathering Facts] ********************************************************************************************
Thursday 16 December 2021  09:07:08 -0800 (0:00:00.110)       0:00:00.110 *****
ok: [vng.cs.east.com]

TASK [disable seLinux] ********************************************************************************************
Thursday 16 December 2021  09:07:35 -0800 (0:00:27.138)       0:00:27.249 *****
[WARNING]: SELinux state change will take effect next reboot
changed: [vng.cs.east.com]

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************
vng.cs.east.com  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

I would like to include a reboot task in my play, to conditionally reboot the server if this warning is issued. I'm not sure how to capture the warning for use in a conditional statement for the reboot task.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are disable SELinux (... which is not recommended at all and should by avoided in any case) via the [`selinux`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/selinux_module.html)_module

```
- name: Disable SELinux
  ansible.posix.selinux:
    state: disabled
```

you may just check the [Return Values](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/selinux_module.html#return-values) and perform further tasks like

```
- name: Reboot if required
  reboot:
    reboot_timeout: 300
  when: reboot_required
```